# as3 button getting clicked 50 px below button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, button

I have an issue. I've narrowed down to my button class where if I click 50-100px below the button sprite area, the mouse.click event listener is triggered.

At one point I thought that a nested issue with sprite children could have caused it, but even adding the button straight to stage has the same effect.

I rewrote the button class from scratch and the same thing is happened.
I'm unsure if this is something that happens because I'm writing pure as3 with the flex framework or something else. Here is the class for the button code:

```
package org.project.ui 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
import org.project.controller.IController;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName; 
/**
 * 
 * 
 */
public class CustomButton2 extends CustomSprite 
{
    protected var _button:Sprite;
    protected var _buttonFunction:Function = null;
    protected var _label:String = "";

    protected var _textField:TextField;
    protected var _textFormat:TextFormat;
    protected var _font:String = "Arial";
    protected var _fontSize:int = 12;
    protected var _fontColor:uint = 0x000000;

    protected var _buttonWidth:int = 110;
    protected var _buttonHeight:int = 30;

    public function CustomButton2(label:String, id:String, w:int, h:int, buttonFunction:Function = null) 
    {
        super(id, content);
        _label = label;         
        _buttonWidth = w;
        _buttonHeight = h;      
        _button = makeButton(label, w, h, buttonFunction);
        addButtonListeners();
        addChild(_button);
    }


    protected function makeButton(label:String, w:int, h:int, buttonFunction:Function = null):Sprite {
        _button = new Sprite();
        _button = drawButton(_button);
        _button.useHandCursor = true;
        _button.buttonMode = true;
        _button.mouseChildren = false;


        _button = addTextField(label, _button);
        return _button;
    }

    protected function addTextField(label:String, button:Sprite):Sprite {
        _textFormat = new TextFormat(_font, _fontSize, _fontColor, false, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);
        _textField = new TextField();
        _textField.defaultTextFormat = _textFormat;
        _textField.name = "textField_" + id;
        _textField.text = _label;
        _textField.selectable = false;
        button.addChild(_textField);

        return button;
    }

    protected function addButtonListeners():void {
        _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
        _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseRollover);
        _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseRollOut);
    }

    protected function mouseClick(e:MouseEvent) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (_buttonFunction) {
            _buttonFunction();
        }
        changeButtonDisplay();

        trace("click");

    }

    protected function mouseRollover(e:MouseEvent) {
        changeButtonDisplay(0xFF0000);
    }

    protected function mouseRollOut(e:MouseEvent) {
        changeButtonDisplay(0xFFCC00);
    }

    protected function changeButtonDisplay(u:uint = 0xFF0000, w:int = 110, h:int = 30):void {
        _button = drawButton(_button, w, h, u);
    }


    protected function drawButton(button:Sprite, w:int = 110, h:int = 30, u:uint = 0xFFCC00):Sprite{
        button.graphics.beginFill(u);
        button.graphics.lineStyle(1);
        button.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, 20);
        button.graphics.endFill();
        button = addTextField(_label, button);
        return button;
    }
}

}
```

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: All fixed. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your `TextField` is extending past the rest of your button.

It doesn't appear as though your setting the text field's bounds, so it will be the default (usually a `100x100` square).

I suggest explicitly setting the text field's width and height to match your button.

```
_textField.width = _buttonWidth;
_textField.height = _buttonHeight;
```

Or instead, if you want all the text visible no matter what, you could use the `autoSize` property to make the text field bounds match the actual text.

```
_textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
I tried adding the width and height as suggested and now mouseover and mouseclick is picking up at the bottom of the screen.
At least I know its a textfield problem now.

Comment: Also I just found out that if I manually enter in 110 for textfield.width and textfield.height as 30 as opposed to a reference to buttonheight and width it works.
textfield.width expects a number not an int.

Comment: You can assign an `int` to a `Number` property.

Comment: To that end,  trace or log the `_buttonWidth` & `_buttonHeight` values right before assigning them to the text field's width/height,  perhaps they are not what you think.